# Wondering how to complete a function that will have the console write out a random string from an array of 20 answers?

Tags: c#

I'm very new to programming and still lack a lot of information, but would like to dive into it and learn from experience/constructive criticism.

My current problem is getting the console to print a random string from a string array. I have some code written out already, but not sure how to initialize it or if it is even the right approach.

Below is the string array and a few other lines of code I thought might work to get me where I need to be, but I know I'm missing a good bit.

```
public static void main()
        {
            string[] randOut = new string[20];
            randOut[0] = "It is certain.";
            randOut[1] = "It is decidedly so.";
            randOut[2] = "Without a doubt.";
            randOut[3] = "Yes- definitely.";
            randOut[4] = "You may rely on it.";
            randOut[5] = "As I see it, yes.";
            randOut[6] = "Most likely.";
            randOut[7] = "Outlook good.";
            randOut[8] = "Yes";
            randOut[9] = "Signs point to yes.";
            randOut[10] = "Reply hazy, try again.";
            randOut[11] = "Ask again later.";
            randOut[12] = "Better not tell you now.";
            randOut[13] = "Cannot predict now.";
            randOut[14] = "Concentrate and ask again.";
            randOut[15] = "Don't count on it.";
            randOut[16] = "My reply is no.";
            randOut[17] = "My sources say no.";
            randOut[18] = "Outlook not so good.";
            randOut[19] = "Very doubtful.";
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine(randOut[rnd.Next(0,19)]);
        }
```

What I hope was that this would allow the console to print out a random string from the list, but after having it write the introductory string, nothing occurs. No errors are found with this code.

Comment: I'm assuming you read the answers underneath. If you're using Visual Studio you'll need to start your application with CTRL+f5 for the console to stay open after the application has finished executing or else it will be in debug mode and close immediately.

Comment: That's correct. I am using visual studio, but I don't think I've come across the problem you're describing thankfully. The CTRL+F5 command is what I normally use.

Comment: If you press the 'play' button as I call it and you go into debug mode, you will. But since you don't, it's fine. It's not an error, just a weird behaviour that I had to google when I first started.

Answer (score 2):

Just after

```
Console.WriteLine(randOut[rnd.Next(0,19)]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

To See the console result.When Main Thread finished its execution in this case  it will finish app.

Answer (score 0):

Place the code below to wait before closing the application.

```cs
...
Console.WriteLine(randOut[rnd.Next(0,19)]);
Console.ReadKey();
```